# Kill a process by PID returned in the output of a command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am working on one batch script where I need to kill the PID of the top row "chrome.exe pid: 2880 TSH\C400677" can someone let me know how could I do that?
I think I need to use for loop.First I need to save the output of the below command and then take first row and from there fetch the PID and kill it.

Is it possible than I can do it in a single commands.Use below command and kill the PID of the all the process one by one.?

```
C:\Users\C400677\Desktop\Handle>Handle.exe -p chrome | find /I "pid"
chrome.exe pid: 2880 TSH\C400677
chrome.exe pid: 6404 TSH\C400677
chrome.exe pid: 3572 TSH\C400677
chrome.exe pid: 5348 TSH\C400677
```

Answer (score 1):

This will kill only the first process in the list:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%# in ('Handle.exe -p chrome^|find /I "pid"') do (
    tskill %%#
    goto :break_for
)
:break_for
```

NOT TESTED!!

remove goto line to kill all chrome processes.

Comment: It's `taskkill` in my Windows 7 and the syntax is `taskkill /pid <pid_number>`, otherwise this seems fine. I guess you could also specify that removing the `goto` line would allow the OP to kill every process, which is what they seem to be additionally asking about at the end of their post.

Comment: @AndriyM - `TSKILL` is part of terminal services and should be available on any windows machines.`TASKKILL` is not available on XP home editions (not sure about home editions of 7/8)